# Using a selected DT column as an input to a plot in a non-embedded Shiny RMD

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I haven't been able to figure out or find any resources for how to build a plot from a user selected column in a shiny formatted RMD. I do not want to have an embedded shiny app in the rmd unless that's the only option.

Normally, I would set an output object like `DT::dataTableOutput("my_datatable")`
Then take the selected column in this way `input$my_datatable_columns_selected` and use that to plot. However, this functionality doesn't seem to exist unless I embed a shiny app within rmd.

Is this possible?

Below is a mini rmd with a selectable table.

Thanks!

````
    ---
    title: "Test"
    output:
        flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        theme: bootstrap
        orientation: rows
    # params:
    runtime: shiny
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    
    library(shiny)
    library(flexdashboard)
    #library(data.table)
    library(DT)
    library(highcharter)
    library(crosstalk)
    
    ```
    
    Info {.sidebar data-width=300}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Example here:
    
    Row
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ### Plot
    
    ```{r, echo=FALSE}
    print("PLOT OUTPUT from column selection")
    ```
    
    Row 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ### mtcars
    
    ```{r, echo=FALSE}
    
    DT::renderDataTable(mtcars,
                        selection = list(mode = "single", target = "column"),
                        options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
    
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to declare the output, and it does work. You need to add the table for the selection to be made from, then designate the render to an object.

If you want to determine what column was selected, that's just like a Shiny app, too. (BTW, I changed the `knitr` option to `echo=F`. That's why my chunk options differ.)

````
### mtcars

```{r yayTables}

DT::dataTableOutput('mtTbl')

output$mtTbl = DT::renderDataTable(
  mtcars, selection = list(mode = "single", target = 'column'),
  options = list(scrollX = TRUE))

```

Column that was selected:

```{r showMe}

renderPrint(input$mtTbl_columns_selected)

```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Kat.  I should have added that I'm trying to run the document in a different script. Using `rmarkdown::render()`. After a bit of research it looks like rmd with `runtime: shiny` can only be run in R or hosted on a server.

My goal was to knit this as an html file and looks like that isn't possible. I get an error when rendering stating that: in output$mtTbl = DT::renderDataTable({ : object 'output' not found.

I'll mark as resolved since you answered my question. I was unaware of the limitations of shiny rmd's.

Comment: You can do this without Shiny. You could even do this without Shiny or RMarkdown. However, you'll have to get creative and use some JS. Without either, `htmltools::browsable()`. With RMD, you can create JS chunks. For example, to get column selected without Shiny: `DT::datatable(mtcars, selection = "none", extensions = "Select", options = list(scrollX = TRUE, select = list(items = 'column')))`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not super confident in my JS skills and had a quick turn around for what I was working on otherwise I'd give that a try. :)